# Get Longest Matching Number (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a table as

```
 pattern | score
    ----------+------
      12345 |    2
     123456 |    2
       1234 |    2
        123 |    2
    1234567 |    3
   12345678 |    3
```

I need output as:

```
  pattern | score
----------+------
   123    |    2
 1234567  |    3
```

the logic is based as get the longest pattern having the same score, i.e 123 has score 2, now if a number starts with 123 then it's score should be 2, same as for pattern 1234567 is the longest pattern having score 3, so no matter what the integer is if it starts with 1234567 then a score of 3 is allot ed to it.

I am not able to figure this out on how to do using sql, though it would be possible but is it worth or doing this using a programming language is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you are asking for:

```
select min(pattern), score
from table t
group by score;
```

For your sample data, it gives the desires results.  If this isn't correct, please edit your question with more detailed sample data to better explain the logic.